# how to extend the height of the controls to the screen height in Angular JS without scrolls?

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

In AngularJS application, I want all the grids in my system to expand on the whole page without vertical scroll. The problem I am having is that when document.ready() function is triggered, the Angular JS controls are not populated yet.

Putting a delay and setting the height after few seconds, when all controls are rendered and populated will solve the problem but it's not a great solution.

How to solve it?

Here's my code

```
var contentHeight = bodyHeight - navbarHeight - footerHeight;
$rootScope.contentHeight = contentHeight;

$scope.prepareTreeHeights = function () {
    $scope.contentHeight = $rootScope.contentHeight;
    $scope.fullTreeHeight = parseInt($scope.contentHeight);
}
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
    $scope.prepareTreeHeights();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried solving your problems with CSS too. I then Flexbox would be a better way to align your items on the page. From my experience calculating heights / withs, layouts in genal with JavaScript is a huge pain and you will run into many more problems then this one...

Comment: Do you have to do this in JS? If not try to use `height:100vh' in your CSS styles if JS is not necessary in your case.